# include and extend behavior on modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I was playing around with `include` and `extend` today and found something I don't quite understand.

```
module Dragon
  def roar
    'roar'
  end
end

module Knight
  include Dragon

  def fight
    'fight'
  end
end

class Other
  extend Knight
end

puts Other.roar # -> 'roar'
```

**Why is it that `roar` is available as a class method on `Other`?** I did `extend Knight` which makes `Knight's` methods available as class methods. `Knight` in turn will `include Dragon` but that should make the `Dragon` methods available as `instance` methods. But that's not the only weird thing going on here, you also can't create instances of modules so why is it that I can `include` on a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You include methods from Dragon module into Knigth module (like mixin).

2) When u extend class, all methods from Knight (Dragon methods have been already included) become class methods of class Other. It is normal behaviour, don't see a problem.

Another question what do u want to achieve?

Comment: Just wanted to understand what was going on and you explained it well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Include makes the roar or fight method available to an instance of a class and extend makes the roar or fight method available to the class itself.